# How to add multiple icon to an array

Tags: javascript, css

I have an array simply like this

```
const data = {
products: [
{
   name: 'example1',   
   icon: <exampleIcon />,
},
{
   name: 'example2'
   icon: <exampleIcon2 />
},
],
};
```

I'm using icons from [React Icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons)

Is it possible for me to add multiple icons to the `icon` part? like three icons in a row like this `exampleIcon exampleIcon exampleIcon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to put multiple icons inside a [react fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
icon: <><exampleIcon /> <exampleIcon2 /></>,
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just wrap your components into a root div like this:

```
const data = {
  products: [
    {
      name: 'example1',
       icon: <div className="wrapper"><exampleIcon /><exampleIcon /><exampleIcon /></div> ,
    },
    {
      name: 'example2',
       icon: <exampleIcon2 />
    },
  ],
};
```

Add this style:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```